# Android Wear wireless charging current tap

Tags: android

Technically this is a question of Google API's and JAVA however it does involve a little electronics; but I'll post it here anyway.

I have an android wearable, the Moto 360, this particular device charges wirelessly; I'd like to pragmatically return some data about the wireless charging process. Specifically I'd like to know how much current the device is pulling. I'm sure there's an ADC in there talking to the CPU and managing the charging state to ensure it doesn't cook it's self, however I don't know if that kind of information is made available to a developer apart from the obvious charge state and battery level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no API to get fine-grained characteristics (current-draw for) charging process.

You can get close to understanding by using the [Battery Historian tool](https://github.com/google/battery-historian) and charting the overall battery level over time.